# android sqlite exception no such table

Tags: java, android, sqlite

I have an app that has a database 'Contact.db' in the assets folder. I am trying to use it to populate my second spinner. But the app crashes and the main error shown is no such table exists

DataBaseHelper.java

```
package com.example.testspinner;

import java.io.FileOutputStream;
import java.io.IOException;
import java.io.InputStream;
import java.io.OutputStream;
import java.util.ArrayList;
import java.util.List;

import android.content.Context;
import android.database.Cursor;
import android.database.SQLException;
import android.database.sqlite.SQLiteDatabase;
import android.database.sqlite.SQLiteException;
import android.database.sqlite.SQLiteOpenHelper;

public class DataBaseHelper extends SQLiteOpenHelper {
    // The Android's default system path of your application database.
    private static String DB_PATH = "/data/data/com.example.testspinner/databases/";
    private static String DB_NAME = "Contact";
    private SQLiteDatabase myDataBase;
    private final Context myContext;

    public DataBaseHelper(Context context) {
        super(context, DB_NAME, null, 1);
        this.myContext = context;
    }

    public void createDataBase() throws IOException {
        boolean dbExist = checkDataBase();
        if (dbExist) {
            // do nothing - database already exist
        } else {
            this.getReadableDatabase();
            try {
                copyDataBase();
            } catch (IOException e) {
                throw new Error(e.toString());
            }
        }
    }

    private boolean checkDataBase() {
        SQLiteDatabase checkDB = null;
        try {
            String myPath = DB_PATH + DB_NAME;
            checkDB = SQLiteDatabase.openDatabase(myPath, null,
                    SQLiteDatabase.OPEN_READONLY);
        } catch (SQLiteException e) {
            // database does't exist yet.
        }
        if (checkDB != null) {
            checkDB.close();
        }
        return checkDB != null ? true : false;
    }

    private void copyDataBase() throws IOException {
        // Open your local db as the input stream
        InputStream myInput = myContext.getAssets().open(DB_NAME);
        // Path to the just created empty db
        String outFileName = DB_PATH + DB_NAME;
        // Open the empty db as the output stream
        OutputStream myOutput = new FileOutputStream(outFileName);
        // transfer bytes from the inputfile to the outputfile
        byte[] buffer = new byte[1024];
        int length;
        while ((length = myInput.read(buffer)) > 0) {
            myOutput.write(buffer, 0, length);
        }
        // Close the streams
        myOutput.flush();
        myOutput.close();
        myInput.close();
    }

    public void openDataBase() throws SQLException {

        // Open the database
        String myPath = DB_PATH + DB_NAME;
        myDataBase = SQLiteDatabase.openDatabase(myPath, null,
                SQLiteDatabase.OPEN_READONLY);
    }
    @Override
    public synchronized void close() {
        if (myDataBase != null)
            myDataBase.close();
        super.close();
    }

    public List<String> getAllData() {
        List<String> set = new ArrayList<String>();
        String selectQuery = "select reg_name from " + "regions";
        SQLiteDatabase db = this.getReadableDatabase();
        Cursor cursor = db.rawQuery(selectQuery, null);
        if (cursor.moveToFirst()) {
            do {
                set.add(cursor.getString(1));
            } while (cursor.moveToNext());
        }
        cursor.close();
        db.close();
        return set;
    }

    @Override
    public void onCreate(SQLiteDatabase arg0) {
        // TODO Auto-generated method stub

    }

    @Override
    public void onUpgrade(SQLiteDatabase arg0, int arg1, int arg2) {
        // TODO Auto-generated method stub

    }
}
```

MainActivity.java:

```
package com.example.testspinner;

import java.io.IOException;
import java.util.ArrayList;
import java.util.List;

import android.os.Bundle;
import android.app.Activity;
import android.view.Menu;
import android.view.View;
import android.widget.AdapterView;
import android.widget.AdapterView.OnItemSelectedListener;
import android.widget.ArrayAdapter;
import android.widget.Spinner;

public class MainActivity extends Activity implements OnItemSelectedListener {
    Spinner s1, s2;

    @Override
    protected void onCreate(Bundle savedInstanceState) {
        super.onCreate(savedInstanceState);
        setContentView(R.layout.activity_main);
        s1 = (Spinner) findViewById(R.id.countries);
        s2 = (Spinner) findViewById(R.id.region);
        s1.setOnItemSelectedListener(this);
        ArrayAdapter<CharSequence> adapter = ArrayAdapter.createFromResource(
                this, R.array.Countries, android.R.layout.simple_spinner_item);
        adapter.setDropDownViewResource(android.R.layout.simple_spinner_dropdown_item);
        s1.setAdapter(adapter);
    }

    @Override
    public boolean onCreateOptionsMenu(Menu menu) {
        // Inflate the menu; this adds items to the action bar if it is present.
        getMenuInflater().inflate(R.menu.main, menu);
        return true;
    }

    @Override
    public void onItemSelected(AdapterView<?> arg0, View arg1, int arg2,
            long arg3) {
        List<String> list = new ArrayList<String>();
        if (s1.getSelectedItem().equals("India")) {
            DataBaseHelper db = new DataBaseHelper(this);
            try {
                db.createDataBase();
                db.openDataBase();
                list = db.getAllData();
                ArrayAdapter<String> adapter = new ArrayAdapter<String>(MainActivity.this,android.R.layout.simple_spinner_item, list);
                adapter.setDropDownViewResource(android.R.layout.simple_spinner_dropdown_item);
                s2.setAdapter(adapter);

            } catch (IOException e) {
                // TODO Auto-generated catch block
                throw new RuntimeException(e);
                //e.printStackTrace();
            }
        }
    }

    @Override
    public void onNothingSelected(AdapterView<?> arg0) {
        // TODO Auto-generated method stub

    }

}
```

logcat:

```
05-28 12:04:12.144: E/AndroidRuntime(11965): FATAL EXCEPTION: main
05-28 12:04:12.144: E/AndroidRuntime(11965): android.database.sqlite.SQLiteException: no such table: regions: , while compiling: select reg_name from regions
05-28 12:04:12.144: E/AndroidRuntime(11965):    at android.database.sqlite.SQLiteCompiledSql.native_compile(Native Method)
05-28 12:04:12.144: E/AndroidRuntime(11965):    at android.database.sqlite.SQLiteCompiledSql.<init>(SQLiteCompiledSql.java:68)
05-28 12:04:12.144: E/AndroidRuntime(11965):    at android.database.sqlite.SQLiteProgram.compileSql(SQLiteProgram.java:143)
05-28 12:04:12.144: E/AndroidRuntime(11965):    at android.database.sqlite.SQLiteProgram.compileAndbindAllArgs(SQLiteProgram.java:361)
05-28 12:04:12.144: E/AndroidRuntime(11965):    at android.database.sqlite.SQLiteProgram.<init>(SQLiteProgram.java:127)
05-28 12:04:12.144: E/AndroidRuntime(11965):    at android.database.sqlite.SQLiteProgram.<init>(SQLiteProgram.java:94)
05-28 12:04:12.144: E/AndroidRuntime(11965):    at android.database.sqlite.SQLiteQuery.<init>(SQLiteQuery.java:53)
05-28 12:04:12.144: E/AndroidRuntime(11965):    at android.database.sqlite.SQLiteDirectCursorDriver.query(SQLiteDirectCursorDriver.java:47)
05-28 12:04:12.144: E/AndroidRuntime(11965):    at android.database.sqlite.SQLiteDatabase.rawQueryWithFactory(SQLiteDatabase.java:1564)
05-28 12:04:12.144: E/AndroidRuntime(11965):    at android.database.sqlite.SQLiteDatabase.rawQuery(SQLiteDatabase.java:1538)
05-28 12:04:12.144: E/AndroidRuntime(11965):    at com.example.testspinner.DataBaseHelper.getAllData(DataBaseHelper.java:95)
05-28 12:04:12.144: E/AndroidRuntime(11965):    at com.example.testspinner.MainActivity.onItemSelected(MainActivity.java:48)
05-28 12:04:12.144: E/AndroidRuntime(11965):    at android.widget.AdapterView.fireOnSelected(AdapterView.java:882)
05-28 12:04:12.144: E/AndroidRuntime(11965):    at android.widget.AdapterView.access$200(AdapterView.java:48)
05-28 12:04:12.144: E/AndroidRuntime(11965):    at android.widget.AdapterView$SelectionNotifier.run(AdapterView.java:848)
05-28 12:04:12.144: E/AndroidRuntime(11965):    at android.os.Handler.handleCallback(Handler.java:605)
05-28 12:04:12.144: E/AndroidRuntime(11965):    at android.os.Handler.dispatchMessage(Handler.java:92)
05-28 12:04:12.144: E/AndroidRuntime(11965):    at android.os.Looper.loop(Looper.java:137)
05-28 12:04:12.144: E/AndroidRuntime(11965):    at android.app.ActivityThread.main(ActivityThread.java:4441)
05-28 12:04:12.144: E/AndroidRuntime(11965):    at java.lang.reflect.Method.invokeNative(Native Method)
05-28 12:04:12.144: E/AndroidRuntime(11965):    at java.lang.reflect.Method.invoke(Method.java:511)
05-28 12:04:12.144: E/AndroidRuntime(11965):    at com.android.internal.os.ZygoteInit$MethodAndArgsCaller.run(ZygoteInit.java:784)
05-28 12:04:12.144: E/AndroidRuntime(11965):    at com.android.internal.os.ZygoteInit.main(ZygoteInit.java:551)
05-28 12:04:12.144: E/AndroidRuntime(11965):    at dalvik.system.NativeStart.main(Native Method)
```

Comment: Maybe your tables in your database have a different names.

Comment: doube checked the table is named 'regions' only

Comment: have you checked if the table inside Your db is really named "regions"? Maybe any uppercase letter or wrong spelled?

Comment: It is lowercase and plural only

Comment: I suppose you are not copying your database but creating just file of that database .Check database size and compare to which in assets folder.

Comment: I copied the database in the assets folder I just want to open that database and read it's contents. It is just a 7KB database

Comment: @user3331111 what's the solution?